# 2D Array with variable internal array length JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

Im currently writing some code that print Pascal's Triangle. I need to use a 2D array for each row but don't know how to get the internal array to have a variable length, as it will also always changed based on what row it is int, for example:

```
public int[][] pascalTriangle(int n) {
    int[][] array = new int[n + 1][]
}
```

As you can see I know how to get the outer array to have the size of Pascal's Triangle that I need, but I don't know how to get a variable length for the row that corresponds with the line it is currently on.

Also how would I print this 2D array?

Comment: `array[x] = new int[y];`, where `y` is the size for a given row (and `x` is the `row`).

Comment: Should I write that in a loop (with x being upped by one each cycle), given that I never know the amount of rows?

Comment: The number of rows is `n + 1`. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Do I need to write that for each row is what I'm saying

Comment: Oh. Yes. You do.

Comment: Do you have a specific output format?

Comment: The assignment asks me to write a method with a return statement (as there isn't void) that is in the form of int[ ][ ] and I don't know how to print that from a main method.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you want to happen is get the size of each row.

```
for(int i=0; i<array.size;i++){//this loops through the first part of array
    for(int j=0;j<array[i].size;j++){//this loops through the now row
          //do something
     }
 }
```

You should be able to use this example to also print the triangle now.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on StackOverFlow. I am a freshman and have just studied Java as part of my degree.
To make every step clear, I will put different codes in different methods.

Say n tells us how many rows that we are going to print for the triangle.

```
public static int[][] createPascalTriangle(int n){
    //We first declare a 2D array, we know the number of rows
    int[][] triangle = new int[n][];
    //Then we specify each row with different lengths
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        triangle[i] = new int[i+1];  //Be careful with i+1 here.
    }
    //Finally we fill each row with numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            triangle[i][j] = calculateNumber(i, j);
        }
    }
    return triangle;
}
//This method is used to calculate the number of the specific location
//in pascal triangle. For example, if i=0, j=0, we refer to the first row, first number.
public static int calculateNumber(int i, int j){
    if(j==0){
        return 1;
    }
    int numerator = computeFactorial(i);
    int denominator = (computeFactorial(j)*computeFactorial(i-j));
    int result = numerator/denominator;
    return result;
}

//This method is used to calculate Factorial of a given integer.
public static int computeFactorial(int num){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
        result = result * i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally, in the main method, we first create a pascalTriangle and then print it out using for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] pascalTriangle = createPascalTriangle(6);
    for(int i = 0; i < pascalTriangle.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < pascalTriangle[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(pascalTriangle[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This will give an output like this:

```
1 
1 1 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1 
1 5 10 10 5 1
```